# How to monitor a AWS S3 bucket with python using boto?

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have access to a S3 bucket. I do not own the bucket. I need to check if new files were added to the bucket, to monitor it.

I saw that buckets can fire events and that it is possible to make use of Amazon's Lambda to monitor and respond to these events. However, I cannot modify the bucket's settings to allow this.

My first idea was to sift through all the files and get the latest one. However, there are a lot of files in that bucket and this approach proved highly inefficient.

Concrete questions:

1. Is there a way to efficiently get the newest file in a bucket?
2. Is there a way to monitor uploads to a bucket using boto?

Less concrete question:

- How would you approach this problem? Say you had to get the newest file in a bucket and print it's name, how would you do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that **AWS Lambda** can be triggered when objects are added to, or deleted from, an Amazon S3 bucket. It is also possible to send a message to **Amazon SNS** and **Amazon SQS**. These settings needs to be configured by somebody who has the necessary permissions on the bucket.

If you have no such permissions, but you have the ability to call `GetBucket()`, then you can retrieve a list of objects in the bucket. This returns up to 1000 objects per API call.

There is **no API call** available to "get the newest files".

There is **no raw code to "monitor" uploads to a bucket**. You would need to write code that lists the content of a bucket and then identifies new objects.

**How would I approach this problem?** I'd ask the owner of the bucket to add some functionality to trigger Lambda/SNS/SQS, or to provide a feed of files. If this wasn't possible, I'd write my own code that scans the entire bucket and have it execute on some regular schedule.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer! I did something similar to your suggestion / my initial idea. In a while loop, I get the list of items, sort them by date and extract the first. I also keep the last new file. If the current newest file is different from the last newest file, it's a new file so I do things to it. Still, I don't think this approach is elegant at all, it takes close to half a minute to order all the items in the bucket. And iterating just once to find the newest isn't much of an improvement either.

Comment: Yes, there are better ways of doing it (Lambda, SQS, SNS, or even storing information in a DynamoDB table) but they all require permissions on the bucket itself. With only read permissions, there's only limited options.

Comment: @RandomGuyqwert Can you please provide the code for getting the new file list from S3?